# missing FROM clause entry for table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table 'marks'

```
id bigserial
name VARCHAR(50)
english, maths, science, sst int
status VARCHAR(10)
```

```
ID  | Name   | Maths | English | Science | SST  | Status
```

I want to create a trigger with a function so that whenever I insert or update marks for a student, it calculates the average of the marks of the student and if that is greater than 40%, the status column should display "Pass" else "Fail" for that particular student.

FUNCTION:

```
marks=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $table$
marks$# BEGIN
marks$# IF (marks.science+marks.maths+marks.sst+marks.english)/400*100>40
marks$# THEN INSERT INTO marks (Status) VALUES ('Pass');
marks$# ELSE
marks$# INSERT INTO marks (Status) VALUES ('Fail');
marks$# END IF;
marks$# END;
marks$# $table$
marks-# language plpgsql;
```

TRIGGER:

```
marks=# CREATE TRIGGER trggr
marks-# AFTER INSERT ON marks
marks-# FOR EACH ROW
marks-# EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger();
```

Whenever I'm trying to insert the data, it is throwing this error:

```
marks=# INSERT INTO marks (name, english, maths, science, sst) VALUES ('Ziyan', 54, 63, 74, 85);
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "marks"
LINE 1: SELECT (marks.science+marks.maths+marks.sst+marks.english)/4...
                ^
QUERY:  SELECT (marks.science+marks.maths+marks.sst+marks.english)/400*100>40
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function trigger() line 3 at IF
```

Comment: I haven't used SELECT statement anywhere but it's still showing me this, any help ?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed several things in your code.

Firstly, you cannot have an `INSERT` operation on the same table inside an `INSERT` trigger because it will have cascading inserts infinitely. I think you wanted an `UPDATE`, You may simply assign `NEW.status` instead by converting it to `BEFORE` Trigger.

You need to `RETURN NEW` from the Trigger if you want the triggered statement to continue modifying the data( `INSERT` ).

Thirdly, your expression to calculate average `%` marks is not right.The 100 should be multiplied to the numerator.

Note that the inserted columns are not referred as `tablename.columnname` but using the `NEW` keyword.Also, I changed your function name to `fn_trigger` instead of the simple `trigger` which is a keyword.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
 $table$
 BEGIN
    IF 100*(NEW.science + NEW.maths + 
            NEW.sst + NEW.english )/400 > 40 THEN 

    NEW.Status =  'Pass'; 
    ELSE
      NEW.Status =  'Fail';
    END IF;

     RETURN NEW;
  END;
 $table$ language plpgsql;


 CREATE TRIGGER trggr
  BEFORE INSERT ON marks
   FOR EACH ROW
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_trigger();
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=28fb1ba877d4519a1028a6795390e98a)

As an alternative, I would go with a `View` like below for this requirement rather than use a Trigger as if someone updates the marks, you would also need to have an `UPDATE` Trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE View v_marks as 
 SELECT science ,maths ,english,sst, 
  CASE WHEN 100 * (science + maths + sst + english ) /400 > 40 
       THEN 'Pass' Else 'Fail'
  END as Status from marks;
```

Comment: thank you so much for this, if I want to update the marks, how will that work for status ?

Comment: @AnkitRana : You will have to change it to `INSERT OR UPDATE OF` Trigger with condition to check for each column change before running the `update`. But, a better solution would be a `View`, see my latest edits.

Comment: Don't use an AFTER trigger and an UPDATE inside the trigger function. Use a BEFORE trigger and *assign* the new values `new.status := 'Fail';` that will be **much** more efficient

Comment: @AnkitRana : Please take a look the modified answer.